# Handling mime type with app, in Android browser

Tags: android, mime-types, browser-plugin

Is there a way to register a mimetype-specific plugin in the Android browser? for example, some programs add "application/specificformat" plugin handler, which is seen with navigator.plugins. I've seen the example code, and I tried doing something like the [example plugin](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/development/samples/BrowserPlugin/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<service android:name=".SamplePlugin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.webkit.PLUGIN" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/applicationmimetype" android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="type" android:value="native" />            
</service>
```

but it doesn't seem to register with the browser. When I look at navigator.plugins on an Android, it is either empty, or only shows Google Gears Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

use webview.getSettings().setPlugInenabled(true) and also setJavaScript in code

you can set mime type using loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)

Comment: I know you do that in your own webview, I was talking about the default web browser.

Comment: Can you give an example of a plugin that is enabled/disabled this way?